# Score Sentiment function in R, for csv file, returns total score not individual score

Tags: r, csv

I am following the answer on:

[Score Sentiment function in R, return always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222946/score-sentiment-function-in-r-return-always-0)
 and trying to run the same for csv with 16000 columns.

Reading csv file

```
sample<-read.csv("C:/Users/manis/Desktop/ORM/rawforpolarity/Comment.csv",header=T)
result=score.sentiment(sample,hu.liu.pos,hu.liu.neg)
```

I am writing the individual scores for each row to csv file as:

```
setwd("C:/Users/manis/Desktop")
write.csv(result, file="result.csv")
```

But the problem is I am getting same total score(for all the rows) at every row level and not individual scores. Can some one please help me calculate score at individual row level?

Answer (score 0):

Once after creating the object, make sure we confirm to look at row wise information using subset:

```
sample<-sample[,1]
```